# Vector Space with inner product

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

I would appriciate your help with the question below :

```
V is a vector space with inner product.

A = {a1,...,ak}   B = {b1,...,bk}  such that :

<ai , bj> = {1 , i = j
            {0 , i != j         for  1 <= i,j <= k
```

**I want to know if spB = (spA)⊥**

(⊥ is a sign for euclidean vector space ,  such that every vector in the subspace is orthogonal to every vector in the complement)

Comment: Certainly not. After all $\langle a_1,b_1\rangle=1$ and not $=0$

Comment: How can that be possibe if for example $\;\langle a_1,b_1\rangle=1\neq0\;$ and thus $\;b_1\rlap{\;\,/}\perp a_1\;$  ?!